# Regex min length on complex match

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^(?P<wrap_0>\()?[-+]?((?P<whole_part>\d+\.?)|(?P<decimal_part>\d*\.\d+))(?(wrap_0)\))$
```

Is there a way to assert that the `whole_part` + `decimal_part` is at least 8 chars in length? In other words, this should match:

```
1029.20384 # yes
102 # no, length of 3 < 8
```

Existing regex here: https://regex101.com/r/rTrCeB/1 (PCRE / php flavor).

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: @saurabh PCRE / php flavor, but no language outside of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an alternation here:

```
^(\d{8,}|(?=[0-9.]{8,})\d+(?:\.\d+))$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^                     from the start of the string
(
    \d{8,}            match a pure number (no decimal component) of 8 or more digits
    |                 OR
    (?=[0-9.]{8,})    assert that 8 or more digits or decimal point occurs
    \d+(?:\.\d+)      then match a number followed by a decimal component
)
$                     end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive lookahead to assert at least 8 times a digit or dot on the right and then match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part.

```
^(?=[\d.]{8,}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[\d.]{8,}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 8 or more times either a dot or digit
- `\d+` Match
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a dot and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqli4l/1)